# bootstrap grid system layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have read some bootstrap grid system documents, but no answer can solve  my question.
I want my html layout like the picture below, is there any way to do this by using Bootstrap grid system.

[image]

Comment: with native use I think its not possible

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible and very easy

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
             both 1 and 3
       </div>
  </div>

 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      both 2 nd 4 grid
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for it :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      4
    </div>
    </div>
```

check fiddle resize the window:https://jsfiddle.net/uL8jsxt2/

Answer (score -1):

you have to follow the bootstrap rules, the grid system was designed for flexibility...many of the answers to layout issues is "nesting"

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
  </div><!--repeat row-->
</div><!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Please consider adding more info to your answer, only code anwsers should be discouraged.